# With new kernel 4.13.0-43 on Xenial syslog is filling up with disk messages

Tags: 16.04, udisks

This didn't happen with the prior kernel 4.13.0-41.

The log is full of these messages that are emitted every couple of minutes.

```
 Error updating ATA smart for /org/freedesktop/UDisks2/drives/ST8000DM004_2CX188_ZCT04MXG: Disk is in sleep mode and the nowakeup option was passed (udisks-error-quark, 13)]
```

I saw a bug report from 2009 that was similar but it was supposedly fixed.

Is this OK? Should I report a bug?  Or is it a "feature" of the new kernel?

** Edit ** I booted into the older kernel and no messages. I'll stay on that one for now until I understand what's going on.

Comment: I just booted with `4.13.0-43` on 16.04.3 LTS and didn't see these messages. But my primary is an NVMe SSD and the secondary ATA type HDD only  has one Windows 10 partition mounted in NTFS format but not used really. Waltnator told me a good trick last night run `journalctl --follow` and see messages in a terminal in real time. I'm using that now and not seeing messages 2 minutes into boot.

Comment: Thanks! I booted into the old kernel and there are no messages, so I'm going to stay on that one for now.  I think I'll open a bug.  Thanks again for the info.

Comment: No worries. I noticed last night `4.13.0-43` was installed along with `4.4.0-something` but I'm actually on the LTS 4.14 kernel chain `4.14.42` so was curious if I could duplicate the problem and rebooted back in time. Just watching Caps play Lightning anyway so not doing much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The messages were caused because at some point in the past I had disabled the `udisks2` service.  Sadly my system notes don't say **why** I did this; ISTR it was because of some problem I was having with an external USB drive.

It seems that the new kernel expects `udisks2` to be running and takes advantage of something it provides, and complains via this error message if it doesn't work.

Enabling `udisks2` and rebooting solved the problem.

I now wait to see why I disabled it in the first place, and resolve to keep better notes!